# Word for Consumer of Technology

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone know of a word that means a person is a consumer of technology, but not necessarily a creator of it? Something that would be similar to "non-technical consumer", or "non-technical user".

Comment: That would be a ***person***. Just as most of us can do things like ***eat, drive, read books***, but we don't have or need special different terms for each of those "consumer" contexts, to distinguish us from ***chefs, mechanics,*** and ***authors***.

Comment: In most contexts, it would would be presumed that somebody speaking of consumers or users of some kind of technology is referring to the people who have not created it, even without any explicit qualification to that effect.

Comment: It wouldn't be correct to characterize a consumer of technology as a *non-technical consumer* or *non-technical user*. Both the consumer and user could be *technical* but not those who created the technology.